# Dealing with Carriage Return and Line Feed on Linux files

Tags: linux, c++98

I have a `c++98` script on linux  in which I read a file from the user from a specific path.
If the file is written on a linux operating system, the end of each line will be the linefeed LF.
Whereas if the file is written on windows, it will end with CR LF. (Carriage Return and Line Feed)

My problem is when the file is written in windows and edited in linux, sometimes if the cursor is at the beginning of the line and a back space is entered, this will only leave the CR which will not be recognised as a new line when reading the file. I am using `ifstream` to read the file line by lie

File Written on Linux

[image: File Written on Linux]

File Written on Windows

[image: File Written on Windows]

File Conflict when migrating from windows to linux

[image: File conflict]

```
bool ConfigParser::loadFile(const std::string filePath)
{
    std::ifstream fio;          // Config file descriptor

    fio.open(filePath.c_str());
    if (fio.is_open())
    {
        int lineNumber = 0;
        std::string line;
        while(std::getline(fio, line))
        {
            lineNumber++;
        }
        fio.close();
    }
}
```

Is there a way to replace all CRs before reading the file or any idea on how to handle such an issue?

Comment: How do you transfer the file between your Windows and Linux systems?

Comment: As for the editing of the files, any decent text editor would recognize the line-endings and handle it properly.

Comment: This is further complicated by the fact that on old Mac systems, the default line ending is CR without LF. I believe best practice is to assume that CRLF, CR, and LF are all valid line terminators.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Just copying and pasting the file. The problem doesn't appear unless the user (on linux) tries to edit the file pasted from windows.

Comment: @DanielH ```ifstream``` does not recognize CR as a new line. In the third image, the IP and channel are read as one line.

Comment: You should show your code that reads the file. You may be able to get the stream to eat the unexpected end-of-lines with `skipws`, but it depends on how you are using the stream. Also see [How to deal with newline char across different platforms](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17192426/608639).

Comment: What do you mean by "just copying and pasting the file". Do you use the Windows explorer (or comparable Linux tool) to copy-paste the files to a USB drive or similar? What editor are your "user" using for the edits?

Comment: And as a possible solution, perhaps you should *reinvent* the old `dos2unix` and `unix2dos` commands? Or just use the [`tr`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/tr.1.html) command to delete the carriage-returns?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude copying and pasting using a USB. The user doesn't have to use a specific editor. I am using ```notepad++``` in the above example and ```gedit``` on linux

Comment: @jww According to your link, I should write my own read line?

Comment: @Hasan - From your problem description, it sounds like yes. It is one of the sharp edges of parsing and standard runtimes.